# How do I convert date from DB2 format to string?

Tags: sql, db2

I want to convert

```
SELECT CURRENT DATE FROM sysibm.sysdummy1;
```

to 20180119 (YYYYMMDD) rather than with the hyphen 2018-01-19 (YYYY-MM-DD)

Comment: what platform and version of DB2?

Answer (score 6):

Found out how to do this,

```
SELECT VARCHAR_FORMAT(current_timestamp,'YYYYMMDD') FROM SYSIBM.SYSDUMMY1;
```

Thanks for the help everyone!

Answer (score 1):

```
select int(current_date) 
from sysibm.sysdummy1
```

and if you really want a string as asked...

```
select char(int(current_date)) 
from sysibm.sysdummy1
```

Answer (score 0):

If your Db2 server runs on Linux/Unix/Windows, then you can use:

`select to_char( current date,'YYYYMMDD') from sysibm.sysdummy1;`

See documentation [here](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSEPGG_11.1.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.sql.ref.doc/doc/r0007108.html).

Comment: Argument 1 of function TO_CHAR not valid.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT VARCHAR_FORMAT(CURRENT DATE, 'YYYYMMDD')   
FROM SYSIBM.SYSDUMMY1
```

If above is not working, use below

```
SELECT VARCHAR_FORMAT(TIMESTAMP(CURRENT DATE), 'YYYYMMDD')   
FROM SYSIBM.SYSDUMMY1
```

Comment: [Code: -171, SQL State: 42815]  [SQL0171] Argument 1 of function VARCHAR_FORMAT not valid.

Comment: which version of DB2 are you using?

Comment: I ran the query before providing the answer, thats why asking. Try with CURRENT_DATE (underscore in between)

Comment: I run the DB2 iSeries for AS/400

Comment: To save everyone's time, you should add that platform information to the *question*  also add the *version*  of the IBM i  that you are using. That's because each version can have different functionality so a correct answer for the current version might not work on older versions.